# How do I have voice typing in my EditText field in Android

Tags: android

How do I have voice typing in my EditText field.

I want to programatically set input type to voice typing for some EditText fields.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few links you might be interested in. I ran the third link and it looks good, but is not exactly what you are looking for, but might help you get moving along.

[Java Code Geeks - Android Voice Recognition Tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-voice-recognition-tutorial.html)

[Android Developers Blogspot - Add Voice Typing to Your IME](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/12/add-voice-typing-to-your-ime.html)

[James Elsey Blogs - Android how to Implement Voice Recognition](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/)