# Android speech Recognizer

Tags: android, android-studio

How to add each values of speechRecognizer to EditText ?
I mean when you can use speech Recognizer after next call the edittext previous editext values delete and only last call value remain.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [How do I have voice typing in my EditText field in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210035/how-do-i-have-voice-typing-in-my-edittext-field-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

It has several ways of implementing one of the simplest way of getting it done is as follows.

```
public void promptspeech(){
    Intent i=new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Say Something!");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(i,VOICE_RESULT );
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException a){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry! Your device does not support speech Language", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I have set the language to default value as set in the mobile devices.
You can get the result by overriding **onActivityResult** method.

Add the following code lines to onActivityResult method

```
if(requestCode ==VOICE_RESULT && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        List<String> result=data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        editTextRemarks.setText(result.get(0));
 }
```

Customized the code as appropriate.Hope this will helps to get the work done.

Comment: Thank u sir...Ok I got this but my question is what happen when u call for the second time..I want The edittext should display both first and second values and so on..hope u understand

Comment: @ANISHSUBEDI you can get the value of the edittext first and then concat with the new value